# set prop element visible after onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set a prop isSelect like true in element Time after onClick,What would be the best way to do this process? I could create a state for this property but I have several buttons how to proceed?

```
const range = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

export default function Schedules() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [hours, setHours] = useState([]);
  const [hoursSelected, setHoursSelected] = useState([]);

  const profile = useSelector(state => state.user.profile);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadAvailable() {
      const response = await api.get(`providers/${profile.id}/available`, {
        params: {
          date: date.getTime(),
        },
      });

      setHours(response.data);
    }

    loadAvailable();
  }, [date]);

  function handleSelectHour(time) {
    setHoursSelected([...hoursSelected, time.time.time]);
  }


  return (
    <Container>
      <ul>
        {hours.map(time => (
          <Time
            key={time.time}
            id={time.time}
            onClick={() => handleSelectHour({ time })}
            available={!time.available}
            isSelected={false}
          >
            <strong> {time.time} </strong>
            <span>{time.available ? 'Select' : ''}</span>
          </Time>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you using hooks?. If that is the case, is isSelected a state value? If that is true, you might need a function on the parent component that does the changing of the value of `isSelected `x pass the function to the Time component alongside the state and bind it on the Time component itself. Let me know if this answers your question

Comment: I added the remaining code above

Answer (score 0):

I would be making a lot of assumptions with my current solution as your question isn't very clear in my opinion. However, you can still reachout if any assumption is incorrect
Assumptions: 
1. isSelect is state value decleared in schedules

```
export default function Schedules(){
  ...
  const [isSelect, setIsSelect] = useState(false)
  <Time
    key={time.time}
    id={time.time}
    onClick={() => {
      // handleSelectHour({ time })
      setIsSelect(!isSelect)
    }}
    available={!time.available}
    isSelect={isSelect}
    setIsSelect={SetIsSelect}
  >
    <strong> {time.time} </
    <span>{time.available ? 'Select' : ''}</span>
  </Time>
}
```

This way, you have passed the value of isSelect and the ability to change its value `setIsSelect` as props value to Time. Within Time, you can set the value of isSelect after the onClick event is emitted.

However, I still do not think this solves all the problem as `handleSelectHour` is `undefined` within Time so you might also need to pass that as props.

Perhaps my assumptions are wrong though

Answer (score 0):

your solution would be right if TIME were a single element, but time is traversed by a map so I would need a state for each time element being persisted

```
 {hours.map(time => (
          <Time
            key={time.time}
            id={time.time}
            onClick={() => {
              setIsSelect(!isSelect);
              handleSelectHour({ time });
            }}
            available={!time.available}
            isSelected={isSelect}
            isSelect={isSelect}
          >
            <strong> {time.time} </strong>
            <span>{time.available ? 'Selecionar' : ''}</span>
          </Time>
        ))}
```